# Place A Variables Address Into Another Variable In C

Tags: c, variables

I was wondering if I could capture a variables address that I could display by using

```
fprintf(stdout, "%p\n", (void*) &var);
```

and actually place it into another variable, without displaying it.

(Into a String variable, not into it's actual address)

I have tested this with setbuf and everything but it still displays the String which I would not want.

I have tried looking everywhere but all I see is using either setbuf or some other means that doesn't fit what I am looking for.

Comment: So you want to place the pointer's address as a string into a `char *`?  Have you tried `sprintf(mystr, "%p", (void*) &var)`?  Here `mystr` would be a pointer to a character array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture a string representation of an address in the same way that you capture any output in a string - by using [`sprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sprintf.html) function:

```
char buf[17];
sprintf(buf, "%p", (void*) &var);
```

At this point `buf` contains a null-terminated string with a representation of `var`'s address suitable for printing.

Of course if you wish to keep the string beyond the scope of `buf` you need to allocate another string dynamically, and `strcpy` your `buf` into it.

Comment: Yes, though probably minus the \n.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
void* pointerToVar = &var;

fprintf(stdout, "%p\n", pointerToVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first post and it worked also.

We also tried a modified version of this and it also works like this.

char a = 5; // Random number, literally has no importance

```
unsigned long long int b = (unsigned long long int) &a;

int num = abs(b);
```

Comment: abs() requires an int parameter, not a unsigned long long int parameter.  using the suggested code causes the compiler to raise a warning.  and the value is already unsigned, so why bother with abs()?

Answer (score -1):

pointer is really just an integer (address). You could do this:

```
float var;
int addr_of_var = (int)(&var);
```

depending on the platform, it might be long int, I think.

Comment: The won't work on most 64bit systems. Use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` instead of `int` or just `void*` for any pointer.

Comment: "*pointer is really just an integer*" this might be true for some implementations, but definitly not for all. For an example you might like to read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation (It's been not so long we used this... ;-))